# XeLaTeX/fontspec/Hebrew TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]

Tags: xetex, fontspec, hebrew

The following document (distilled from Pandoc issue) fails to compile with `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].` error.

```
\documentclass[hebrew,]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont[]{Noto Sans Hebrew}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[]{hebrew}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\section{File test-case.md}\label{file-test-case.md}
A list
\begin{itemize}
\item
  Hello World.
\item
  חַ
\item
  Goodbye World.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

The complete error is

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
<to be read again> 
                   \q_nil 
l.10 \section{File test-case.md}
                                \label{file-test-case.md}
```

It disappears when I remove the `\defaultfontfeatures` line.

Comment: I do not get this error, but I get plenty of other errors. For the code to work, change the preamble to `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{hebrew}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{Noto Sans Hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Noto Sans Hebrew}`.
Don't forget to specify `\newfontfamily\hebrewfont`. You also don't have to load `fontspec` explicitely, because `polyglossia` loads it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that polyglossia with language hebrew redefines `\rmfamily`. Its code now contains a `\addfontfeature` and it implicitly calls the option `Scale=MatchLowercase`.

The code of the `Scale`-option on the other side contains `\rmfamily`. And so there is a loop of `\rmfamily` calling `\rmfamily`.

You can test the issue with this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:Nn \__fontspec_calc_scale:n
 {
  \group_begin:
    %\rmfamily %breaks
    \fontfamily{\rmdefault}\selectfont %works
    \__fontspec_set_font_dimen:NnN \l__fontspec_tmpa_dim {#1} \font
    \__fontspec_set_font_dimen:NnN \l__fontspec_tmpb_dim {#1} \l_fontspec_font
    \tl_gset:Nx \l__fontspec_scale_tl
     {
      \fp_eval:n { \dim_to_fp:n {\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim} /
                   \dim_to_fp:n {\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim} }
     }
    \__fontspec_info:n {set-scale}
  \group_end:
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setmainfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Noto Sans Hebrew}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[]{hebrew}

\begin{document}

{\rmfamily blub }

\end{document}
```

I'm not quite sure who to blame -- `polyglossia` or `fontspec` -- but on the whole I think that a user command like `\rmfamily` should not be used in the internal code of `fontspec`.

Comment: I confirm the above test case breaks/works as suggested by the commented lines.